# How to add conditional types inside a function param based on the already given input

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The title is pretty confusing, so let me explain.

**What I want to archive**
This referrers to the code below. I want to type the `route` property based on the `types` property to be either a `string` or a `function that returns a string`.

**The code**
First let's start with a working example.

```
// A typescript hack to define types without providing actual values
const defineArgTypes = <
  T extends {
    args?: ArgumentsBase | null;
  }
>() => null as any as T;

interface ArgumentsBase {
  queryParams?: Record<string | number | symbol, any>;
}

type BaseActionMap = Record<
  string,
  {
    types?: { args?: ArgumentsBase };
  }
>;

type ActionMapItem<Item extends BaseActionMap[string]> = {
  types?: Item['types'];
};

type ActionMap<BaseConfig extends BaseActionMap> = {
  [Property in keyof BaseConfig]: ActionMapItem<BaseConfig[Property]>;
};

type ConfigMapItem<Item extends BaseActionMap> = {
  route: Item['types'] extends { args: ArgumentsBase }
    ? (args: Item['types']['args']['queryParams']) => string
    : string;
};

type ConfigMap<AMap extends ActionMap<any>> = {
  [Property in keyof AMap]: ConfigMapItem<AMap[Property]>;
};

const defineActions = <Data extends BaseActionMap>(
  actions: Data,
  config: ConfigMap<Data>
) => {
  // code inside here is not relevant to the question
};

const config = defineActions(
  {
    getTodos: {},
    getTodo: {
      types: defineArgTypes<{ args: { queryParams: { id: string } } }>(),
    },
  },
  {
    getTodo: {
      route: (d) => `todos/${d.id}`,
    },
    getTodos: {
      route: 'todos',
    },
  }
);
```

In the code above you can see, that I need to define the "actions (getTodos, getTodo)" 2 times.

Is there a way to reduce this to the following without loosing conditional types for the `route` properties?

```
const config = defineActions(
  {
    getTodos: {
      route: 'todos',
    },
    getTodo: {
      types: defineArgTypes<{ args: { queryParams: { id: string } } }>(),
      route: (d) => `todos/${d.id}`,
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  That's basically a type that is the union of two types that have a common property--the "discriminant--that Typescript can use to narrow the union.  So, simplifying your example slightly, you want a type like this:

```js
type Config = {
  types?: undefined
  route: string
} | 
{
  types: {id:string}
  route: (args:{id:string})=>string
}
```

The `types` property is the discriminant.  If it's undefined, TS will know to narrow the type to the first member of the union.  If it's `{id:string}`, TS will narrow to the second member of the union.  You could, of course, have more than three options.

Now, it looks like you want `route` in the second case to actually use some of the typing from `types`, so we'll make this union use a generic, so it looks like this.  But it's still fundamentally a discriminated union.

```js
type Config<T extends {id: string}> = {
  types?: undefined
  route: string
} | 
{
  types: T
  route: (args:T)=>string
}
```

Then it's just a matter of using it in your `defineActions` function with some appropriate type parameters so TS can infer the types of your generics and voila:

```js
function defineActions<T extends {id:string}, U extends Record<string,Config<T>>>(configs:U){}

const config = defineActions(
  {
    getTodos: {
      route: 'todos',
    },
    getTodo: {
      types: { id: "myId" },
      route: (d) => `todos/${d.id}`,
    },
  }
);
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKlCAPYCBAEwGcoBvFYgLilOACcUE0BfAPigF5KAoKFFCRSAfjoBXEhFQIIxAVEZwJhOg2as%20bKAB8ofCouERSdLIuWqIdABQBDRmjNYAlNw4aWabXz5IpAGNgFEQoYhkWCABBYNCEUmxcAiIySmoaL1Y2ABooAFVkwhJyACUIQLhGYgwstBz4ZHRsDlbbSqbnGnzXCjY-DoYoDtQ0HnDIuViQxFJbRSNBQTQIYCw4YjgzfiWlqzUoAHJgDa3DnMVBXMuoFbXTukXdoXBTR6gMqAAiAFsQAEliF8oNdnkoVAdbMRXDwuAADE6bUgAegAJBRiAA6ahsOEXXagkF8VwAbiAA)

OK, one little caveat:  you might wonder--how does TS know that `types` is the discriminant vs `route`?  The answer is--it' doesn't.  In fact, given that `types` can be undefined, TS is actually probably using `route` to discriminate, but it doesn't really matter here because your types don't overlap.  If you wanted to make sure it discriminated based on `types`, you would want to make the rest of the type different, e.g.:

```js
type Config<T extends {id: string}> = {
  types?: undefined
  basicRoute: string
} | 
{
  types: T
  complexRoute: (args:T)=>string
}
```

But I don't think that's needed for what you are trying to do here.

I've obviously simplified your example, but I don't think I've done it in any way that's material to your question.  Please clarify, if you think I missed something.